# Understanding the concept of measurability of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If a random variable $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_0}$-measurable, where $\{ \mathcal{F} \} _{ t \geq 0}$ is an underlying filtration, does that mean that from the time $t_0$ onwards, the random variable $X$ "becomes a constant" (i.e. there's no more randomness within $X$ after time $t_0$, i.e. we know it's value)?

EDIT:
I'm sorry for my original question being so unclear. I don't how to state it much better (which just points out how much I have no idea what's happening here), but I'm gonna try...

It's often said that the filtration represents the "flow of information", each next $\sigma$-algebra being bigger than the previous one which should represent the growth in our knowledge. So, if we are at time $t_0$ and we have "our knowledge" contained in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{t_0}$, since $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_0}$-measurable, it follows that $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_{t_0}]=X$. So, my interpretation of that last statement is that we have enough knowledge so that our expectation of $X$ is exactly $X$, so $X$ is not random any more ($X$ is observable at time $t_0$)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here.  It doesn't seem to correspond to a precise mathematical statement that can be answered yes or no.

Comment: "my interpretation of that last statement is that we have enough knowledge so that our expectation of X is exactly X" Yes. "so X is not random any more?" No. What is your definition of expectation exactly? There seems to be some vagueness there...

Comment: For every event $F$ from the $\mathcal{F}_{t_0}$ $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathbb{E}[X|F]$ is equal to the sum of the all possible values $X(\omega)$, where $\omega \in F$, divided by the $\mathbb{P}(F)$? So my "logic" is, if we know which event $F$ from $\mathcal{F}_{t_0}$ has happened, in the case of $X$ being $\mathcal{F}_{t_0}$-adapted, knowing $F$ is enough to know the value of $X$...But just as I'm writing all of this, it's all becoming more abstract to me :( I understand nothing.

Comment: Here's one interpretation (reminiscent of the game "20 Questions"): If you know the answer to the question "Is $\omega$ an element of $F$?" for each $F\in \mathcal F{t_0}$, then you know the value of $X(\omega)$.